# Perl line doesn't work when moved to separate function

Tags: perl

I have an array that may or may not look like `[0, 1]` and I want to test for that.

This code (inside a method) works:

```
sub some_other_method {
    my $self = shift;
    ...
    if (scalar @myArray == 2 && @myArray[0] == 0 && @myArray[1] == 1) {
        # this will successfully catch arrays that look like [0, 1]
    }
}
```

If I move the contents of the `if` into a separate method and then call it, it doesn't work.

```
sub is_warning {
    my $self = shift;
    my @array = shift;
    return scalar @array == 2 && @array[0] == 0 && @array[1] == 1;
}

...

sub some_other_method {
    my $self = shift;
    ...
    if ($self->is_warning(@myArray)) {
        # this will not catch arrays that look like [0, 1]
    }
}
```

If I add a `print @array;` to `is_warning`, it just prints a single number.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `my ($self, @array) = @_` in is_warning instead as shift only shifts one item off of @_ in a sub

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn is that the only way to pass an array by reference? Sorry, I come from c# and I'm new to perl.

Comment: @Otterbein Yes, I got the same result with and without parentheses.

Comment: passing by reference is explained here http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

Comment: Like @KeepCalmAndCarryOn said: passing arrays or hashes as an reference is the best way to work with them in subroutines. You can reference every array or hash with `\@array` or `\%hash`. And dereference it with `@{$array}[0]` or `%{$hash}{key}`.

Comment: ALWAYS `use strict; use warnings;` It says: `Scalar value @myArray[0] better written as $myArray[0] at  ...`

Comment: @Otterbein: Youre comments are misleading. Nothing you have said is correct except for how to take the reference of arrays and hashes

Comment: To reinforce [@Toto's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787898/perl-line-doesnt-work-when-moved-to-separate-function#comment63043907_37787898), unless you have `no warnings 'syntax'` in place, or you're using a very old version of Perl, you should have seen warning messages like `Scalar value @myArray[0] better written as $myArray[0]`. An array element, being a scalar, should begin with a dollar `$`. What you have written is a one-element *array slice*

Comment: @Borodin I have changed that now as well. The environment I'm developing in doesn't show warnings unless there is also an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've missed something crucial about Perl - a subroutine is only *ever* passed a list of scalar values in `@_`. So to pass an array, you need to use one of the techniques in subroutines `stuff` and `other` below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

sub stuff {
   my ( $arg, @other_args ) = @_;
   print Dumper \@other_args;
   print "$_\n" for @other_args;
}

sub other {
   my ( $arg, $array_ref ) = @_;
   print Dumper $array_ref;
   print "$_\n" for @$array_ref;
}

my $param = "fish";
my @array = ( "wiggle", "wobble", "boo" );

stuff( $param, @array );
other( $param, \@array );
```

In `stuff` the subroutine is handed a list of values to do with what it will. In the `other`, it's given two values - `$param` and a *reference* to `@array`.

The reason you're only getting `1` in your case, is that `shift` is only pulling a single value off `@_`. So any extra arguments are getting left behind. You'll be able to see this with;

```
print Dumper \@_;
```

Comment: I didn't know that about how arrays were passed. This fixed my problem, thank you!

Answer (score -6):

Please remove the my $self = shift; line from is_warning function and test it again.

Please try below script:

#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;

sub is_warning {

```
my @array = @_;
print Dumper \@_;
return scalar @array == 2 && @array[0] == 0 && @array[1] == 1;
```

}

sub some_other_method {

```
my @myArray = (0,1);
if (is_warning(@myArray)) {
 print "\nif inside some : @myArray\n";
}
```

}

some_other_method();

Comment: That'll break things even worse. That'll put the object as the first element of `@array`. Not to mention that you've just lost your ability to use `$self` inside the method.